# React native location when device's location in turned off

Tags: android, react-native, jsx

My android app crashes if device's location is turned off when I request permission to get location . how can I fix this? here is my `getLocation()` function:

```
    getLocation = () => {
  try {
    navigator
    .geolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(position => {
      const location = JSON.stringify(position);
      this.writeItemToStorage(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
      this.setState({location: location, latitude: position.coords.latitude, longitude: position.coords.longitude});
    }, error => Alert.alert(error.message), {
      enableHighAccuracy: false,
      timeout: 20000,
      maximumAge: 10000
    });
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e);
  }

}
```

I set the **lat** and **long** in `asyncstorage`

Comment: by crash, you mean the try catch block alerts the error message?

Comment: No , the app quits with no error

Comment: where do you import navigator?